# How will this statement be interpreted by the compiler?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

In XCode 4.2, I find that I can write a statement like this:

```
[obj = obj method];
```

And there is no error or warning about this.

So, I want to know how the compiler will interpret this? Is this the same as:

```
obj = [obj method];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn up your warning levels. Clang *will* emit a warning (`-Wself-assign`):

```
warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'NSObject *' to itself [-Wself-assign]
                  [obj = obj method];
```

It is *not* the same as `obj = [obj method];`. It is interpreted as:

```
obj = obj;
[obj method];
```

and the compiler can just omit the self-assign. That is, this program prints `a`:

```
NSString * a = @"a";
NSString * b = @"b";
NSLog(@"%@", b = a);
```

…but why would you write a program using this exact statement? It will be confusing to interpret or just awkward, for many *people*.

Comment: Thanks for replay.I find this code in my project,and I change it to obj = [obj method];

Comment: @zxhfirefox so it's awkward and/or confusing to both of us =)

Comment: yeah,I just want to know why there is no warning and how it is explained.

Comment: Could you tell me how to turn up the warning levels? I use LLVM GCC4.2.

Comment: add `-Wself-assign` to `WARNING_CFLAGS` and occasionally compile with clang to test for this.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will do the assignment, then it will call the method. In a simple test you can see the results:

Define 2 object that both support the same method:

```
@interface testA : NSObject
- (NSString*)o;
@end
@interface testB : NSObject
- (NSString*)o;
@end
@implementation testA
- (NSString *)o
{
    return @"A";
}
@end
@implementation testB
- (NSString *)o
{
    return @"B";
}
@end
```

Run a simple test case:

```
testA *objA = [[testA alloc] init];
testB *objB = [[testB alloc] init];
NSLog(@"test: %@", [objA = objB o]);
```

The output is:

```
test: B
```

Yes there are warnings, but as you say the code is not in error.

Taking it a step further you can see that objA has been reassigned:

```
NSLog(@"test: %@", [objA o]);
```

outputs:

```
test: B
```

Comment: Thanks for your test and replay too. oh, I find that your name is similar Justin..